# Grouping of Dependencies in Maven 3

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build-automation

I am using maven 3 for building my huge multi module project. I have nearly 80 projects and **many dependencies are used by many project** thus makes me to add the same dependency entry in all my projects. In case if i am updating/moving any of my dependency to its latter or earlier version I need to update in all other projects which uses that dependency which is quite impossible.More over it is not possible to create a parent pom for set of projects which has same dependency.

```
Is there any plugin just to map as below in a pom of parent project


<dependency>somegroup:somefact:anyV<dependency>
<projects>
 <project>somegroup:somefact:anyV</project>
</projects> 

or is it possible to implement a plugin on my own </br>
or whether maven provide any other way to do this in its style.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven has a concept of [importing dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies).  The documentation says that this feature is for cases where extending a base POM is not possible.  I have not used this feature so I'm not sure how it works, might be what you are looking for though.

Comment: the key is to use `<scope>import</scope>`

Comment: If I am using import as scope then if i am removing a dependency from a project say project A I need to take care of other projects which include project A as dependency in dependency management. is there any other way

Comment: As far as I know, parent POMs and importing dependencies as described are the only ways to re-use dependency configuration.  Instead of creating one POM with lots of import dependencies, you could create several smaller ones, and only import the dependencies each file needs.

Comment: instead of importing a dependencies I plan to go with dependency management so that i can at least make sure all my projects uses same version of a 3rd party jars.more over creating several pom will cost me more time.